# Shell scripting in nested directories

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm having an issue where I am trying to run commands on all folders within a directory.

for instance:
PWD is /home/user/Documents
I want my program/script to work through

```
/home/user/Documents
/home/user/Documents/directory1
/home/user/Documents/directory1/foo
/home/user/Documents/directory2
/home/user/Documents/directory2/bar
```

etcetera running the command:

```
tranalyzer -r <file in folder> -w OUT_<name of folder>
```

I'm also hoping to delete all files which DON'T have the extension .dmp

If there a tutorial someone could point me to or assistance they would offer, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Where is `tranalyzer` from?

Comment: it's just a program for unix (http://tranalyzer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Explain what you mean by `OUT_<name of folder>`. Do you mean `OUT_directory1/foo`? `directory1/OUT_foo`? `OUT_directory1_foo`? Something else?

Comment: no sorry I probably complicated things with that OUT_ is my naming convention to signify the output from tranalyzer and <name of folder> is the name of the folder the file resides in. If the file was in OUT_directory1/foo it would be named OUT_foo

Comment: @HansSanft Thank you for the clarification; I've updated appropriately. That said, this doesn't make much sense -- this means if you had multiple dump files in one folder, you'd be giving the same output filename for each. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Charles Duffy that will never happen, reason being I already ran a script which puts each file in a directory with it's name (minus the extension) basically what my question in this thread was to me is "How do you delete the contents of a nested directory structure minus the key files and clean up the directory if the program has been run before". I do that so that all the output files for a given input file are nicely placed in one directory because I run multiple different programs on the dmp files to analyse the flows.

Comment: Perhaps not the best way to do things but I'm a bit green as far as research practices go and this was the best way I could think of to keep things from getting messy. Also I suppose by "never happen" I should say in my case specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# iterate over a NUL-delimited stream of directory names
while IFS='' read -r -d '' dirname; do
  # ...then list files in each directory:
  for file in "$dirname"/*; do
    # ignore directory contents that are not files
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    # delete files which do not have the .dmp extension
    if [[ $file != *.dmp ]]; then
      rm -f "$file"
      continue
    fi
    # run analysis tool
    tranalyzer -r "$file" -w "OUT_${dirname##*/}"
  done
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

Comment: tried running it and got "line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Comment: @HansSanft Was missing a `done` for the nested loop. Try again.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the slow reply.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this command to work you must be in the top directory containing the directories you'd like to recurse over.

```
set -f
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n' 
for file in `find . -type f`;
do
     tranalyzer -r "$file" -w OUT_<name of folder>
done
IFS="$OIFS"
set +f
```

Comment: This fails very, very badly if any files have names with spaces in them. Even worse is if someone makes a malicious filename: Think of a file named `out/ /etc/passwd /hello`.

Comment: Setting `IFS` to `$'\n'` is not an adequate solution to the problem -- first, filenames can legitimately contain newlines (try `mkdir $'foo/ \n/etc/passwd\n/bar'` -- it works); second, it doesn't turn off glob expansion, so a file named `*` would be replaced with a list of files in the current directory.

Comment: Better; I've removed my `-1`. However, you still need to quote `$file`, or filenames can pass arbitrary arguments to `tranalyzer`. (Also, you still need to fill out `<name of folder>`).